# Using IIF expression in Access 2007 SQL Select Statement

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I've looked around pretty thoroughly for an answer but I can't see why what I'm trying to do doesn't work:

I'm trying to build a query to provide data for a continuous form.  I'm trying to achieve something like a bank statement where the debits and credits are in separate columns. I also want a running total but I haven't got that far yet.

This is my query :

```
SELECT ACTransaction.*, TransactionCategory.TC_Description, 
TransactionCategory.TC_Sign, ACCategoryGroup.ACCG_Description, 
ACCategory.ACC_Description, ACCategoryClass.ACCC_Description, 
ACSubCategory.ACSC_Description,  IIf([TC_Sign]="-1",[ACT_ValTTC],"") AS 
Spend, IIf([TC_Sign]="1",[ACT_ValTTC],"") AS Receive
FROM TransactionCategory INNER JOIN (ACSubCategory INNER JOIN 
((ACCategoryClass INNER JOIN (ACCategoryGroup INNER JOIN ACCategory ON 
ACCategoryGroup.ACCG_ID = ACCategory.ACC_CategoryGroupID) ON 
ACCategoryClass.ACCC_ID = ACCategory.ACC_CategoryClassID) INNER JOIN 
ACTransaction ON ACCategory.ACC_ID = ACTransaction.ACT_CategoryID) ON 
ACSubCategory.ACSC_ID = ACTransaction.ACT_SubCategoryID) ON 
TransactionCategory.ID = ACTransaction.ACT_TransCategoryID;
```

There are a lot of lookups but the key is that I want to put the [ACT_ValTTC] from the ACTransaction transaction into either the 'Spend' or 'Receive' columns according to the value of [TC_Sign] which can be either '1' or '-1' (it is used as a multiplier elsewhere in the system).

When the query runs I get #ERROR in the column. The last resort is to populate a temp. table in my form and use that as the data source for the form but that's very inefficient, especially as I'll have to rebuild the temp. table each time a transaction is added. I'd much rather have a query I can Requery. Mind you... it depends how hard/impossible building a running total in a query is!

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The likely source of your error is the quotes. `"-1"` is a string containing the text `-1`, while without the quotes, it's an integer with a value of minus one. If you're comparing a string to an integer, you get an error, that's why you get `#ERROR` in the column.

Omit the quotes, and it will likely run fine.

```sql
SELECT ACTransaction.*, TransactionCategory.TC_Description, 
TransactionCategory.TC_Sign, ACCategoryGroup.ACCG_Description, 
ACCategory.ACC_Description, ACCategoryClass.ACCC_Description, 
ACSubCategory.ACSC_Description,  IIf([TC_Sign]=-1,[ACT_ValTTC],"") AS 
Spend, IIf([TC_Sign]=1,[ACT_ValTTC],"") AS Receive
FROM TransactionCategory INNER JOIN (ACSubCategory INNER JOIN 
((ACCategoryClass INNER JOIN (ACCategoryGroup INNER JOIN ACCategory ON 
ACCategoryGroup.ACCG_ID = ACCategory.ACC_CategoryGroupID) ON 
ACCategoryClass.ACCC_ID = ACCategory.ACC_CategoryClassID) INNER JOIN 
ACTransaction ON ACCategory.ACC_ID = ACTransaction.ACT_CategoryID) ON 
ACSubCategory.ACSC_ID = ACTransaction.ACT_SubCategoryID) ON 
TransactionCategory.ID = ACTransaction.ACT_TransCategoryID;
```

Comment: Good Grief! You wouldn't believe how long I've spent trying to sort this out! Removing the quotes worked perfectly. Thank-you very much! I've just got to work out the running totals now...